# How to print a single column in this R datatype?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have an output of a function which when captured in a variable claims it is a list.

```
> typeof(fc)
[1] "list"
```

Here are the first few lines of how `fc` looks like

```
  Point       Forecast       Lo 80     Hi 80       Lo 95     Hi 95
  10229      -2.237542 -5.81116452  1.336080 -7.70292589  3.227841
  10230       1.683324 -3.19974731  6.566396 -5.78468918  9.151337
  10231       3.893685 -1.32257692  9.109948 -4.08389942 11.871270
  .......
```

How to I make a vector with only say the `Forecast` column from this type. I googled around and figured that I should say `fc$Forecast`. But when I do that I get `NULL` printed. Much appreciate your time/help. Thanks.

As requested: The last few lines from dput output:

```
Names = c("method", "model", "level", 
"mean", "lower", "upper", "x", "xname", "fitted", "residuals"
), class = "forecast")
```

And the first few lines.

```
structure(list(method = "ARIMA(4,0,2) with non-zero mean", model 
= structure(list(coef = structure(c(0.261848480125606, 0.55212561713038,       
0.00823985719608051, -0.051126398268002, -0.369141509818343, 
1.60863444159457, -0.0928857946719395, -0.0901626797717415, 
0.0526652165617547, -0.242259088064732, 0.164509902811429, 
-0.149744064351169, 0.108818836027556, -0.0143040675162776
), .Names = c("ar1", "ar2", "ar3", "ar4", "ma1", "ma2", "intercept", 
"S1", "C1", "S2", "C2", "S3", "C3", "S4", "C4")), sigma2 = 1.3269817639389, 
var.coef = structure(c(0.494
```

Inbetween it is just a wall of 3 tuples.

Comment: @jason. from your data it looks like a `data frame` to me. using `typeof` will return `list` even for a data frame, since it is essentially a list of columns. can you try `class(fc)` to check what class it is. also if you can try `dput(fc)` and paste the output in your question, it would help.

Comment: @jason, paste the data into your original question. This is highly unreadable to say the least.

Comment: Can you print the full output of `str(fc)`?

Comment: @sacha, here it is http://www.isimplebin.com/CT8Y29XBhz

Comment: It looks like an object of class "forecast" comes from the forecast package. Have you looked at the documentation for accessors for the forecast class?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't seem to contain info on how to parse the output. This is the manual http://medipe.psu.ac.th/cran-r/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the output of print.forecast which is not what the forecast-object actually looks like internally (as can be seen from the fragments of str(fc). AND ... The name of the first column is not "Forecast" but rather `Point Forecast" (which will need quoting because of the embedded spaces). So after looking at print.forecast with getAnywhere I predicted you get your desired vector with the obvious modification of this (following execution of the example in help(forecast.Arima):

```
> as.data.frame(forecast(fit))$`Point Forecast`
 [1] -0.7725430  0.4591482  0.8732595  1.0124943  1.0593135  1.0750607  1.0803599  1.0821453
 [9]  1.0827486  1.0829539   ### "works"
```

Therefore... try:

```
as.data.frame(fc)$`Point Forecast`
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `fc$mean`. This is fully documented in the help file for `forecast()`.

Comment: I should have waited, eh? Thks, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

To print a single column from a data read,

```
#Reading Data
data <- fread("data.csv")

#printing Data
str(data)
```

Output:

```
id | Name | Father's Name | Birth
---+------+---------------+---------
1  | Abel | Tilaun        | 1994 BC
2  | Jon  | Snow          | 283 AC
3  | Ned  | Stark         | 263 AC
```

The next step is to print out the single column of your choosing, it could be `Name` or `Birth`. For this example, I will use Name

```
#use this to print the single column    
data[,'Name',drop=FALSE]
```

Output

```
id | Name  
---+------
1  | Abel  
2  | Jon   
3  | Ned
```

Or the other way is to use `$`, This is used to refer to an element in a list or a column in a data frame.

```
data$Name  # This will print out everything that is contained in column
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score -1):

I get this a lot. Instead of trying to figure where or how the data is stored in each different package I use, I just copy and paste the data I need from the output to a text file and use readLines().

Don't copy the headers, when they have spaces it messes things up:

In the above, I copied your output:

```
df <- read.table(file="http://www.bertelsen.ca/R/dump.r")

df


     V1        V2        V3       V4        V5        V6
1 10229 -2.237542 -5.811165 1.336080 -7.702926  3.227841
2 10230  1.683324 -3.199747 6.566396 -5.784689  9.151337
3 10231  3.893685 -1.322577 9.109948 -4.083899 11.871270
```

So in this case, I would assume you're wanting to see just `df$V2`

Comment: -1 That is about as epically-silly a solution as is possible. You are kidding, right? I don't down-vote often but I will make an exception this time!

Comment: I'd bet money it's faster than trying to figure out the object structure for every different package one might use. If I'm just doing line by line analysis, it works wonderfully. Output is notoriously painful to identify in the structure of an object.

Comment: Faster? Possibly. Wrong? Yup. Are you happy loosing precision in the output? The printed representation is **not** the actual object. And if you really need to grab printed output, `capture.output()` is your friend.

Comment: What do you do when you re-run your analysis on updated data?  Every time you copy/paste, you introduce the possibility of error.

Comment: I agree with you both. Better, cheaper, faster - choose 2. I generally use this for situations where I'm running line by line analysis on the fly. Wrong? It depends on how detailed you need to be, most of my work only requires accuracy up to the second decimal. Thanks for the pointer to capture.output(), that'll be useful!